# log4cxx output directory

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx

How can i configure log4cxx that it will write the logs in a specific directory?

The tutorial site which i have used is from here, i want to use daily rolling logs.

[Log4cxx Tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Log4cxx.html)

After spending some time googling I have tried adding the following line but it seems not to work, now i would appreciate some help.

```
<param name ="directory" value = "/var/log/myapp/"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Log4cxx uses a config file similar to log4j 
so in the config file have something like

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=/var/log/myapp
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Then in your code intialize the logging system

```
log4cxx::PropertyConfigurator::configure("config.props");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the file name with the whole directory path like

```
 <param name="File" value="/var/log/myapp/logfile" />
```

below the appender tag. And below your triggerPolicy tag set the param name="DatePattern" as you like.